# Change CI to 95% in Logistic Regression

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using the following code which I found in the link below:

```
model = smf.logit("Covid_pos ~  C(Age_Group_N, Treatment(0))", data = df_merged2).fit()
model_odds = pd.DataFrame(np.exp(model.params), columns= ['OR'])
model_odds['z-value']= model.pvalues
model_odds[['2.5%', '97.5%']] = np.exp(model.conf_int())
model_odds
```

This code is great but I would like to set the CI to 95% instead of the 2.5%. Is it possible? In doing a bit a surfing, I found that the default is typically set to an alpha of .05 (95%) but this doesn't seem to be the case for this code.

[image]

https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.OLSResults.conf_int.html

https://www.pythonfordatascience.org/logistic-regression-python/

Comment: This is a 95% CI, it's two tails so you have 2.5% on one side and another 2.5% (i.e. 100% - 97.5%) on the other side. This adds up to 5%, i.e. there is 95% within the interval.

Comment: @Dan Thanks -sorry, rusty with my stats. I just included a picture of the output which lead to my confusion!